# Row combination choices based on condition - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, common-table-expression

I have a working SQL query which returns the following results:

[image]

What I'm looking to be able to do is for MySQL to calculate the `sum` of the weight column and present combinations of rows from the above table in which the `sum(Weight) <= 300`. An example of the expected results using the table above would be:

[image]

My questions about this are: is this possible from with MySQL? Would I need to execute multiple SQL queries and how would I be able to produce the results illustrated above? Is it possible to achieve the first table and the combinations from one query?

Comment: It almost certainly can be done, but it would take someone better at SQL than me to efficiently answer your question.

Comment: @CatoMinor Appreciate the curiosity in the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not sure how exactly you envision returning 3 result sets from one query, and why there are only three -- (1,4) and (2,3) would also be valid combinations. So, I'll assume it was just a general example, and you want the **complete** result in **some** form*.

Let's say you have this table (I've added one row to make it more generic, you example would only produce 2-element combinations):

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM t1;
+------+--------+
| id   | weight |
+------+--------+
|    1 |    100 |
|    2 |    120 |
|    3 |    200 |
|    4 |     96 |
|    5 |     50 |
+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With [MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-102/), you can use a [recursive CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to achieve your goal, e.g.

```
WITH RECURSIVE comb(id,ids,weights,sumweight) AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        CAST(t1.id AS CHAR) AS ids, 
        CAST(weight AS CHAR) AS weights, 
        weight AS sumweight 
    FROM t1 
    WHERE weight <= 300 
  UNION 
    SELECT 
        t1.id AS id, 
        CONCAT(comb.ids,',',t1.id) AS ids, 
        CONCAT(comb.weights,',',weight) AS weights, 
        t1.weight + comb.sumweight AS sumweight 
    FROM t1 JOIN comb ON (comb.id < t1.id) 
    HAVING sumweight <= 300 
) SELECT ids, weights, sumweight FROM comb;
```

You'll get this:

```
+-------+------------+-----------+
| ids   | weights    | sumweight |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 1     | 100        |       100 |
| 2     | 120        |       120 |
| 3     | 200        |       200 |
| 4     | 96         |        96 |
| 5     | 50         |        50 |
| 1,2   | 100,120    |       220 |
| 1,3   | 100,200    |       300 |
| 1,4   | 100,96     |       196 |
| 1,5   | 100,50     |       150 |
| 2,4   | 120,96     |       216 |
| 2,5   | 120,50     |       170 |
| 3,4   | 200,96     |       296 |
| 3,5   | 200,50     |       250 |
| 4,5   | 96,50      |       146 |
| 1,2,5 | 100,120,50 |       270 |
| 1,4,5 | 100,96,50  |       246 |
| 2,4,5 | 120,96,50  |       266 |
+-------+------------+-----------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query above is not perfect, it is just to give an idea of the possible solution. The result seems correct, and you can improve and polish representation according to your needs.

For your second question, *"Is it possible to achieve the first table and the combinations from one query?"*, you didn't say how you got the first table, so it's hard to give a precise example, but in any case it surely should be possible. The most obvious way is to take whatever query you used to get that result set, wrap it into a view, and then use this view instead of `t1` table in the above example.

Comment: thank you! I believe this may be the answer I am looking for. I will apply it and will mark as the answer upon confirming it works. You are 100% right with the disclaimer, apologies